# Manga with a female main character who gets betrayed by her sister

Tags: story-identification, manga

Basically, it was this girl that gets betrayed by her sister. She was super kind and her sister kills her, and then she goes back in time. She finds out how evil his sister was and she decides that she will turn everybody against her sister.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the names of any of the characters or locations?

Comment: Unfortunately, that practically describes a genre in and of itself. Were they human? White? Blonde? Nobles? Adventurers? Was it set in modern times? Mediaeval? Renaissance? Was there magic other than the rebirth?